# How to write a bazel select macro that works inside or outside of defining workspace?

Tags: bazel

In a workspace `@base`, suppose I have a "macro" in main/macros.bzl such as:

```
def if_development(if_true, if_false = []):
    return select({
        "//main:development": if_true,
        "//conditions:default": if_false
    })
```

And in main/BUILD:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

config_setting(
    name = "development",
    values = { "define": "MODE=development" },
)
```

Now I want to be able to load this macro from a different workspace, `@child`, e.g.:

```
load("@base//main:macros.bzl", "if_development")
```

Then it will fail because `//main:development` is not resolved against the `@base` workspace, it's resolved against the `@child` workspace.

```
ERROR: /path/to/child/src/BUILD:3:1: no such package 'main': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '//src:bar'.
```

However, if I fully qualify it,  as in:

```
def if_development(if_true, if_false = []):
    return select({
        "@base//main:development": if_true,
        "//conditions:default": if_false
    })
```

Then it will work in `@child`, but fail when used inside the defining workspace, `@base`, because apparently you can't refer to your own workspace using the `@main` notation:

```
ERROR: /path/to/base/src/BUILD:3:1: no such package '@base//main': error loading package 'external': The repository named 'base' could not be resolved and referenced by '//src:bar'.
```

How can I refer to `@base//main:development` in the macro in a way that will work inside and outside the defining workspace?

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug!  //main:development should be resolved as @base//main:development automatically.  I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1425) for it.

As a (kind of annoying) workaround, you could redefine the config setting in @child//main.